# Insert choice XSD and error message invalid content

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm trying to create an XML schema file. I try to put an  in , I have looking for a solution, and I found this one (Modified for my case)

```
    <xsd:element name="msgBLOB">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="mimeType"    type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:attribute name="msgType"     type="xsd:NMTOKEN" />
                <xsd:attribute name="storeMethod" type="xsd:NMTOKEN" />
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="MsgOrValue">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice>
            <xsd:element ref="msgBLOB"       />
            <xsd:element ref="metaDataValue" />
        </xsd:choice>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>  
<xsd:element name="MetaDataEntry">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:all>                                           
            <xsd:element ref="metaDataName"/>
            <xsd:element ref="MsgOrValue" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element ref="metaDataType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element ref="correlation"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

But, that doens't work.

I have an error message

> ERROR: Element 'msgBLOB': This element is not expected.
>       ERROR: Element 'msgBLOB': This element is not expected.
>       ERROR: Element 'msgBLOB': This element is not expected.
>       ERROR: Element 'msgBLOB': This element is not expected.
>       ERROR: Element 'metaDataValue': This element is not expected.
>       ERROR: Element 'metaDataValue': This element is not expected.
>       ERROR: Element 'metaDataValue': This element is not expected.
>       ERROR: Element 'metaDataValue': This element is not expected.
>       ERROR: Element 'metaDataValue': This element is not expected.

Full XML file :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<MonitoringEntries>
    <MonitoringEntry><msgDateTimeStamp>2015-08-27T22:13:00</msgDateTimeStamp>
        <direction>Received</direction>
        <senderCode>JP GIS</senderCode>
        <receiverCode>Panasonic Energy Europe</receiverCode>
        <formatCode>EDIFACT</formatCode>
        <typeCode>ORDERS</typeCode>
        <subTypeCode>*</subTypeCode>
        <communicationMethod>FILE</communicationMethod>
        <statusID>Successful</statusID>
        <acknowledged>N/A</acknowledged>
        <division>6325cf87dd80f4b6a1c1e5b43b69bcc5c08cb501</division>
        <documentID>0003587782</documentID>
        <MetaDataEntries>
            <MetaDataEntry>
                <metaDataName>IDOC Message</metaDataName>
                <msgBLOB mimeType='text/plain' msgType='base64' storeMethod='file'>ozeruoziruzo</msgBLOB>
            </metaDataEntry>
            <MetaDataEntry>
                <metaDataName>Readable Version</metaDataName>
                <msgBLOB mimeType='text/html' msgType='base64' storeMethod='file'>erzrz</msgBLOB>
            </MetaDataEntry>
            <MetaDataEntry>
                <metaDataName>Filesize</metaDataName>
                <metaDataType>Technical</metaDataType>
                <correlation>No</correlation>
            </MetaDataEntry>
        </MetaDataEntries>
    </MonitoringEntry>
</MonitoringEntries>
```

XSD :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <!-- Déclaration des éléments -->

    <xsd:element name="msgDateTimeStamp"        type="xsd:dateTime" />
    <xsd:element name="direction"               type="xsd:string"   />
    <xsd:element name="senderCode"              type="xsd:string"   />
    <xsd:element name="receiverCode"            type="xsd:string"   />
    <xsd:element name="formatCode"              type="xsd:string"   />
    <xsd:element name="typeCode"                type="xsd:string"   />
    <xsd:element name="subTypeCode"             type="xsd:string"   />
    <xsd:element name="communicationMethod"     type="xsd:string"   />
    <xsd:element name="statusID"                type="xsd:string"   />
    <xsd:element name="acknowledged"            type="xsd:string"   />
    <xsd:element name="division"                type="xsd:string"   />
    <xsd:element name="documentID"              type="xsd:string"   />
    <xsd:element name="metaDataName"            type="xsd:string"   />
    <xsd:element name="metaDataType"            type="xsd:string"   />
    <xsd:element name="metaDataValue"           type="xsd:string"   />
    <xsd:element name="correlation"             type="xsd:string"   />

    <xsd:element name="msgBLOB">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:simpleContent>
                <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                    <xsd:attribute name="mimeType"    type="xsd:string" />
                    <xsd:attribute name="msgType"     type="xsd:NMTOKEN" />
                    <xsd:attribute name="storeMethod" type="xsd:NMTOKEN" />
                </xsd:extension>
            </xsd:simpleContent>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="MsgOrValue">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element ref="msgBLOB"       />
                <xsd:element ref="metaDataValue" />
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="MetaDataEntry">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>                                           
                <xsd:element ref="metaDataName"                                 />
                <xsd:element ref="MsgOrValue"       minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />                          
                <xsd:element ref="metaDataType"     minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xsd:element ref="correlation"      minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="MetaDataEntries">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="MetaDataEntry" maxOccurs="unbounded"  />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="MonitoringEntry">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="msgDateTimeStamp"     />
                <xsd:element ref="direction"            />
                <xsd:element ref="senderCode"           />
                <xsd:element ref="receiverCode"         />
                <xsd:element ref="formatCode"           />
                <xsd:element ref="typeCode"             />
                <xsd:element ref="subTypeCode"          />
                <xsd:element ref="communicationMethod"  />
                <xsd:element ref="statusID"             />
                <xsd:element ref="acknowledged"         />
                <xsd:element ref="division"             />
                <xsd:element ref="documentID"           />
                <xsd:element ref="MetaDataEntries"      />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>


        <!-- Schéma XSD -->

    <xsd:element name="MonitoringEntries">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="MonitoringEntry" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: You should post your XML and the full schema. Right now, it can be anything from badly structured XML to namespace problems.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the XML document is lacking the intermediate MsgOrValue element between MetaDataEntry and msgBLOB.

If you do not want this intermediate level, you can use substitution groups instead of a choice, like so:

```
<xsd:element name="msgBLOB" substitutionGroup="MsgOrValue">
  ...
</xsd:element>

<xsd:element name="MsgOrValue" abstract="true"/>
```

Here is the complete modified schema against which I successfully validated your XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <!-- Déclaration des éléments -->

  <xsd:element name="msgDateTimeStamp"        type="xsd:dateTime" />
  <xsd:element name="direction"               type="xsd:string"   />
  <xsd:element name="senderCode"              type="xsd:string"   />
  <xsd:element name="receiverCode"            type="xsd:string"   />
  <xsd:element name="formatCode"              type="xsd:string"   />
  <xsd:element name="typeCode"                type="xsd:string"   />
  <xsd:element name="subTypeCode"             type="xsd:string"   />
  <xsd:element name="communicationMethod"     type="xsd:string"   />
  <xsd:element name="statusID"                type="xsd:string"   />
  <xsd:element name="acknowledged"            type="xsd:string"   />
  <xsd:element name="division"                type="xsd:string"   />
  <xsd:element name="documentID"              type="xsd:string"   />
  <xsd:element name="metaDataName"            type="xsd:string"   />
  <xsd:element name="metaDataType"            type="xsd:string"   />
  <xsd:element name="metaDataValue"           type="xsd:string"   />
  <xsd:element name="correlation"             type="xsd:string"   />

  <xsd:element name="msgBLOB" substitutionGroup="MsgOrValue">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
          <xsd:attribute name="mimeType"    type="xsd:string" />
          <xsd:attribute name="msgType"     type="xsd:NMTOKEN" />
          <xsd:attribute name="storeMethod" type="xsd:NMTOKEN" />
        </xsd:extension>
      </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="MsgOrValue" abstract="true"/>

  <xsd:element name="MetaDataEntry">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:all>                                           
        <xsd:element ref="metaDataName"                                 />
        <xsd:element ref="MsgOrValue"       minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />                          
        <xsd:element ref="metaDataType"     minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xsd:element ref="correlation"      minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
      </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="MetaDataEntries">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="MetaDataEntry" maxOccurs="unbounded"  />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="MonitoringEntry">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="msgDateTimeStamp"     />
        <xsd:element ref="direction"            />
        <xsd:element ref="senderCode"           />
        <xsd:element ref="receiverCode"         />
        <xsd:element ref="formatCode"           />
        <xsd:element ref="typeCode"             />
        <xsd:element ref="subTypeCode"          />
        <xsd:element ref="communicationMethod"  />
        <xsd:element ref="statusID"             />
        <xsd:element ref="acknowledged"         />
        <xsd:element ref="division"             />
        <xsd:element ref="documentID"           />
        <xsd:element ref="MetaDataEntries"      />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>


  <xsd:element name="MonitoringEntries">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="MonitoringEntry" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're not aware that it's possible to generate XSD schema using Visual Studio (you didn't mention that you're using it, but it still might be useful).

So I've downloaded your xml, opened in my VS and picked XML -> Create Schema as seen in following screenshot:

[image: How to create XSD schema]

Please note that there's a typo in Line 19.

`</metaDataEntry>` should start with capital letter and loook like `</MetaDataEntry>`

When I corrected it, VS generated me this XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="MonitoringEntries">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="MonitoringEntry">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="msgDateTimeStamp" type="xs:dateTime" />
              <xs:element name="direction" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="senderCode" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="receiverCode" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="formatCode" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="typeCode" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="subTypeCode" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="communicationMethod" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="statusID" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="acknowledged" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="division" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="documentID" type="xs:unsignedInt" />
              <xs:element name="MetaDataEntries">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="MetaDataEntry">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element name="metaDataName" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="metaDataType" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="correlation" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="msgBLOB">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:simpleContent>
                                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                  <xs:attribute name="mimeType" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                  <xs:attribute name="msgType" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                  <xs:attribute name="storeMethod" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                </xs:extension>
                              </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

If this is not what you're asking for and you can't use VS, please ignore.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna try it